# R: split a data-frame, apply a function to all row-pairs in each subset

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I am new to R and am trying to accomplish the following task `efficiently`.

I have a `data.frame`, `x`, with columns: `start`, `end`, `val1`, `val2`, `val3`, `val4`. The columns are sorted/ordered by `start`.

For each `start`, first I have to find all the entries in `x` that share the same `start`. Because the list is ordered, they will be consecutive. If a particular `start` occurs only once, then I *ignore* it. Then, for these entries that have the same `start`, lets say for one particular `start`, there are 3 entries, as shown below:

entries for `start=10`

```
start end val1 val2 val3 val4
   10  25    8    9    0    0
   10  55   15  200    4    9
   10  30    4    8    0    1
```

Then, I have to take 2 rows at a time and perform a `fisher.test` on the `2x4` matrices of `val1:4`. That is,

```
row1:row2 => fisher.test(matrix(c(8,15,9,200,0,4,0,9), nrow=2))
row1:row3 => fisher.test(matrix(c(8,4,9,8,0,0,0,1), nrow=2))
row2:row3 => fisher.test(matrix(c(15,4,200,8,4,0,9,1), nrow=2))
```

The code I wrote is accomplished using `for-loops`, traditionally. I was wondering if this could be **vectorized** or improved in anyway.

```
f_start = as.factor(x$start) #convert start to factor to get count
tab_f_start = as.table(f_start) # convert to table to access count
o_start1 = NULL
o_end1   = NULL
o_start2 = NULL
o_end2   = NULL
p_val    = NULL
for (i in 1:length(tab_f_start)) {
    # check if there are more than 1 entries with same start
    if ( tab_f_start[i] > 1) {
        # get all rows for current start
        cur_entry = x[x$start == as.integer(names(tab_f_start[i])),]
        # loop over all combinations to obtain p-values
        ctr = tab_f_start[i]
        for (j in 1:(ctr-1)) {
            for (k in (j+1):ctr) {
                # store start and end values separately
                o_start1 = c(o_start1, x$start[j])
                o_end1   = c(o_end1, x$end[j])
                o_start2 = c(o_start2, x$start[k])
                o_end2   = c(o_end2, x$end[k])
                # construct matrix
                m1 = c(x$val1[j], x$val1[k])
                m2 = c(x$val2[j], x$val2[k])
                m3 = c(x$val3[j], x$val3[k])
                m4 = c(x$val4[j], x$val4[k]) 
                m = matrix(c(m1,m2,m3,m4), nrow=2)
                p_val = c(p_val, fisher.test(m))
            }
        }
    }
}
result=data.frame(o_start1, o_end1, o_start2, o_end2, p_val)
```

Thank you!

Comment: vectorization is a good idea, you should check out the `plyr` package for approaches to this problem.  However ... it is very likely that the bottleneck in your code is the Fisher exact test evaluation, so you are likely to end up with more compact code but not much faster code. (I'd be happy to be proved wrong.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Ben Bolker suggested, you can use the `plyr` package to do this compactly. The first step is to create
a wider data-frame that contains the desired row-pairs. The row-pairs are generated using the `combn` function:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame( start = c(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 end = 1:8, 
                 v1 = sample(8), v2 = sample(8), v3 = sample(8), v4 = sample(8))

require(plyr)
z <- ddply(x, .(start), function(d) if (nrow(d) == 1) NULL
                                      else {
                                        row_pairs <- combn(nrow(d),2)
                                        cbind( a = d[ row_pairs[1,], ],
                                               b = d[ row_pairs[2,], ] )
                                      })[, -1]
```

The second step is to extract the `p.value` from applying the `fisher.test` to each row-pair:

```
result <- ddply(z, .(a.start, a.end, b.start, b.end), 
                function(d) 
                     fisher.test(matrix(unlist( d[, -c(1,2,7,8) ]), 
                                        nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))$p.value  )


> result
  a.start a.end b.start b.end         V1
1       2     2       2     3 0.33320784
2       2     2       2     4 0.03346192
3       2     3       2     4 0.84192284
4       3     5       3     6 0.05175017
5       3     5       3     7 0.65218289
6       3     5       3     8 0.75374989
7       3     6       3     7 0.34747011
8       3     6       3     8 0.10233072
9       3     7       3     8 0.52343422
```

Comment: @Arun -- absolutely right -- I fixed the bug. And always glad to pull people away from Matlab :)